# DllNotFoundException for x86 UWP DLL

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, uwp, augmented-reality

[Screenshot of the dll inspector.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FE6TE.png) I have created x86 UWP DLL using the OpenCV NuGet package. Now I am trying to use that DLL within Unity, but it throws a `DllNotFoundException`, though all its dependent DLLs are in Assets/Plugins/x86 folder. I am trying to access webcam from the DLL itself. Same thing works for x64 standalone app. Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you give a screenshot of the dll inspector？

Comment: @DiZhang please check the screenshot of the dll inspector.